# How to mock Stripe in Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, mocking, stripe-payments, phpunit

I'm using this package for stripe

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php

I'm trying to mock Stripe so I can test refunds and other functionalities.

```
class StripeRefundStrategy implements RefundStrategyInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        Stripe::setApiKey(config('stripe.SecretKey'));
    }

    public function customer()
    {
        // TODO: Implement customer() method.
    }

    public function refund(string $id)
    {
        dd(Refund::create([
            'id' => 'test',
            'amount' => 500,
            'currency' => 'usd'
        ]));
    }
}
```

This is my class that I have so far and below is the test that I've tried to write:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    Stripe::setApiKey('TestKey');
    $mock = Mockery::mock(Stripe::class);
    $mock->shouldReceive('create')->with('TestKey')->once();

    $this->app->instance(Stripe::class, $mock);
    $this->refundStrategy = $this->app->make(StripeRefundStrategy::class);
});

it('can refund product', function () {
    asUser()->assertAuthenticated();

    $this->refundStrategy->refund('ch_3MmlLrLkdIwHu7ix0snN0B15');


})->group('paymentRefunds');
```

I still haven't faked anything, because I can't even get to fake the ApiKey. I'm assuming that all is happening because the methods are static. I've tried to use `overload:` when mocking, but that did not work too.

[image: Response from test]

Comment: Maybe you can implement Laravel Cashier (Stripe): https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/billing#testing

Comment: Yes, I guess there is no easy way. It's a code base that it's already written and implemented the php package of stripe. I need to make refund functionality and I wanted to write test for it but...

Answer (score 1):

You would want to look at [Stripe Mock](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-mock) for a mock HTTP server that responds like the real Stripe API, and works with all programming languages.

Comment: Is there any easier way to do this?